# Databricks SQL nondeterministic expressions using DELETE FROM

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-sql

I am trying to execute the following SQL clause using Databricks SQL:

```
DELETE FROM prod_gbs_gpdi.bronze_data.sapex_ap_posted AS HISTORICAL_DATA
WHERE 
    HISTORICAL_DATA._JOB_SOURCE_FILE = (SELECT MAX(NEW_DATA._JOB_SOURCE_FILE) FROM temp_sapex_posted AS NEW_DATA)
```

The intention of the query is to delete a set of rows in a **historical data table** based on a value present in a column of **new data table**.

For reasons that I cannot understand it is raising an error like:

> Error in SQL statement: AnalysisException: nondeterministic expressions are only allowed in
> Project, Filter, Aggregate, Window, or Generate, but found:
> (HISTORICAL_DATA._JOB_SOURCE_FILE IN (listquery()))
> in operator DeleteCommandEdge

It seems it is not accepting a subquery inside the where clause. That's odd for me, as in the Databricks documentation [Link](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/delta-delete-from.html#examples) it is acceptable.

I even tried other types of predicates, like:

```
(SELECT FIRST(NEW_DATA._JOB_SOURCE_FILE) FROM temp_sapex_posted AS NEW_DATA)

(SELECT DISTINCT NEW_DATA._JOB_SOURCE_FILE FROM temp_sapex_posted AS NEW_DATA)

IN (SELECT NEW_DATA._JOB_SOURCE_FILE FROM temp_sapex_posted AS NEW_DATA)
```

None of them seems to take effect in executing the query successfully.

What's even odd for me is that I was able to accomplish a similar case with a slightly different query, as it can be seen in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74102705/how-to-upsert-data-with-multiple-source-rows-matching-the-target-table-in-databr/74103675#74103675).

Comment: Same here. Curious to know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I have created demo_table1 & demo_table2 for querying purpose. I have created the following query carrying the similar purpose. *I haven’t considered double aliases and have given straight query using subquery, it also depends on data frame in usage use a normal pandas data frame*. it works fine for me.

```
 delete from demo_table1 as t1 where t1.age = (select min(t2.age) from demo_table2 as t2);
```

[image: Databricks SQL snippet]